# Room unique field не становиться уникальным

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-room

Поле `id_name` не становиться уникальным и позволяет добавлять идентичные дублирующие записи.

```
@Entity(
        indices = {
                @Index(value = { "id_name" }, unique = true)
        }
)
public class TableTest {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    public long ids;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "id_name")
    public String idName;
    public String role;
    public String thumb;
    public String profile;
}
```

Room последний, 2.2.5

Вставляем как `List<TableTest>`, опции вставки - при неудаче замена объекта.

```
 @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
  public List<Long> insert(List<TableTest> tag);
```